# Symfony 2 - Join returns less results when object has no associated children

Tags: symfony, join, doctrine

I've been googling for a while now and I guess I just have trouble stating my question the correct way.

I have a Product and my Product has "optional" ProductImages associated with it.
When I lazyload the products everything works as expected but I'd like to join my images prior to reduce my total amoutn of queries.

Here's the code:

```
    $qb->select('product')
       ->from('FocumaTCBundle:Product', 'product')
       ->join('product.ProductType', 'type')
       ->join('product.ProductImages', 'productImage')
       ->where('type.id = :productTypeId')
       ->setParameter('productTypeId', $PRODUCT_HOTEL_TYPE);
```

This however returns less results then without the join. I'm not sure how
to create an "optional" join :(

Thanks for some help on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `leftJoin`:

```
 $qb->select('product')
   ->from('FocumaTCBundle:Product', 'product')
   ->leftJoin('product.ProductType', 'type')
   ->leftJoin('product.ProductImages', 'productImage')
   ->where('type.id = :productTypeId')
   ->setParameter('productTypeId', $PRODUCT_HOTEL_TYPE);
```

Comment: ok - found the issue: I used setMaxResults and apperantly this doesn't work with joints. Using Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator now :-)